How to find the probability generating function for the random variable X?
The Exercise:
Let $N$ be a geometrically distributed random variable with parameter $q \in (0, 1)$, and let $X$ be the number of successes in $N$ coin tosses, where each toss has a probability of success $p \in (0,1)$. Determine the generating function $g_X(s)$ of $X$ and use it to compute the expected value of $X$.
Clarifying Definition of the Generating Function in this Context:
First of all for clarification what I mean with generating function:
The generating function of a probability distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb{N}$ with $\mu(\{k\})=:p_k$ is given as
$$g_{\mu}(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k \cdot s^k $$
with $s\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the function is defined, i.e. the series converges.
My Approach to the First Part and My Question (skip to the result if you do not want to read):
We are given that the conditional distribution of $X$ is a binomial distribution to the parameters $N$ and $p$
Thus the generating function of this conditional probability distribution is given as
$$g_{\displaystyle b_{N,p}}(s)=(ps + 1-p)^N = \mathbb{E}[s^X | N ]$$
now, using the law of iterated expectations I yield that
$$g_{\mathbb{P^X}}(s)=\mathbb{E}[s^X]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[s^X | N ]]=\mathbb{E}[(ps + 1-p)^N]= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(ps+1-p)^n \cdot q \cdot (1-q)^{n-1} = \dots = \frac{\displaystyle q \cdot (ps+(1-p))}{\displaystyle 1-(ps+1-p)(1-q)}$$
for
$$s < \frac{\displaystyle 1-(1-p)(1-q)}{\displaystyle p(1-q)}$$
because only for these the geometric series converges.
My question now is if my result for $g_{\mathbb{P^X}}(s)$ is correct?

The probability generating function for a geometric distribution ($N\sim\mathcal{Geo}_1(q)$) is $$g_N(z)=\mathsf E(z^N) = \dfrac{qz}{1-(1-q)z}\qquad\text{for }\lvert z\rvert<(1-q)^{-1}$$
And as you noted, for a (conditional) binomial distribution ($X\mid N\sim\mathcal{Bin}(N,p)$ we have$$g_{X\mid N}(s)=\mathsf E(s^N\mid N)=(ps+1-p)^N$$
So, indeed:$$\begin{align}g_X(s) &= \mathsf E(g_{X\mid N}(s))\\&=\mathsf E((ps+1-p)^N)\\&=g_N(ps+1-p)\\&=\dfrac{q(ps+1-p)}{1-(1-q)(ps+1-p)}&&\text{for }\lvert ps+1-p\rvert<(1-q)^{-1}\end{align}$$
